# Canyon Grail headset play

Tags: fork, gravel, steering

I got new Grail CF SL 8 and my headache started when I realized I cannot make headset play stop.
After tightening all the screws to exact values I can still produce play on my steering wheel.

Description, I stand over my bike and hold both brakes fully. Then I start to push bike forward and backwards and I can see my forktube covered with cap going forward and backward (gap becomes smaller and bigger depending on the movement).

All the screws inside are:

1. 2x rear to lock the plastic plate to the fork (fixate steering wheel)
2. 1x top cover
3. 1x transitional plate

[image]

https://www.canyon.com/on/demandware.static/-/Library-Sites-canyon-shared/default/dw46151b4d/explosiondrawings/2020/grail/R061-01_R064-01-ME_BOM.pdf

Tnx for help in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just tightening the screws will not resolve the issue. There is a precise but quite simple procedure to follow. You can find a number of very good explanatory videos on the internet. GCN has a recent one on unboxing that specific bike that might be useful.

The usual procedure takes three steps:

1. Undo the pinch bolt(s) on the stem, normally two, left and right on the stem by one turn
2. Tighten the top bolt until play disappears while the bar still moves freely from side to side. This requires some sensitivity.
3. Tighten the pinch-bolts with the recommended torque!!

Then recheck the free movement of the bar and re-adjust if required.

Answer (score 2):

If your headset continues to loosen up, make sure the steerer tube is 100% completely grease-free where the stembolts clamp onto it. Rubbing alcohol is good for this

Comment: Thank you for posting your solution! However, would you please be a little clearer and more specific? If you could take a picture to illustrate it that would be perfect. If not, we have a canonical post that may help you with the terminology: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts